# I logged the file while nutch is crawling i am not getting 399054 SCHEDULE_REJECTED,5892 URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW

Tags: nutch

while crawling i saw it showing

```
Generator: number of items rejected during selection:
Generator:     67  HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW
Generator:      3  MALFORMED_URL
Generator: 399054  SCHEDULE_REJECTED
Generator:   5892  URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW
```

I understand `67 HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW`,`3  MALFORMED_URL`

I did not understand what it means `399054  SCHEDULE_REJECTED`,`5892  URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW`.

Can anyone explain what it means.

Comment: A  long story in short form. It is due to timestamp set for next time URL fetched. It is set via db.fetch.interval.default and default value is 30 days.

Answer (score 3):

[Generator](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-1.17/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Generator.java) phase has different [counters](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counters.html) to know filtered or skipped url's in Genertor MapReduce phase.

1. SCHEDULE_REJECTED

> ```
> if(!schedule.shouldFetch(url, crawlDatum, curTime)){
>                 context.getCounter("Generator", "SCHEDULE_REJECTED").increment(1);
>                 return;}
> ```

As per the property defined in nutch-site.xml default **schedule** value is [DefaultFetchSchedule](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-1.17/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/DefaultFetchSchedule.java)

```
db.fetch.schedule.clas = org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule
```

**shouldFetch method in AbstractFetchSchedule** will decide where to allow url for now or not in to Fetcher Phase.

```
public boolean shouldFetch(Text url, CrawlDatum datum, long curTime) {
    // pages are never truly GONE - we have to check them from time to time.
    // pages with too long a fetchInterval are adjusted so that they fit within
    // a maximum fetchInterval (segment retention period).
    if (datum.getFetchTime() - curTime > (long) maxInterval * 1000) {
      if (datum.getFetchInterval() > maxInterval) {
        datum.setFetchInterval(maxInterval * 0.9f);
      }
      datum.setFetchTime(curTime);
    }
    if (datum.getFetchTime() > curTime) {
      return false; // not time yet
    }
    return true;
  }
```

above logic say the URL once fetched in the last iterations can be fetched once again in the upcoming iterations when it's fetchTime is expired and the window of fetchTime is decided by `db.fetch.interval.default` and default values is 30 days.

shouldFetch makes sure that a url once **successfully fetched will be once again retried fetching only after 30days** otherwise rejected in generator.

2. WAIT_FOR_UPDATE (Default value to wait is 7 days )
   This counter only makes sense when you enabled `generate.update.crawldb=true` otherwise it does not have any sense.

> This counter will be used to track highly-concurrent
> environments, where several generate/fetch/update cycles may overlap,
> setting this to true ensures  that generate will create different
> fetchlists and **it uses **crawl.gen.delay** to ensure different fetchlists**.
> crawl.gen.delay  defines how long items  **already generated are blocked** and (default is 7 days)

```
LongWritable oldGenTime = (LongWritable) crawlDatum.getMetaData()
              .get(Nutch.WRITABLE_GENERATE_TIME_KEY);
      if (oldGenTime != null) { // awaiting fetch & update
        if (oldGenTime.get() + genDelay > curTime) // still wait for
          // update
          context.getCounter("Generator", "WAIT_FOR_UPDATE").increment(1);
        return;
      }
```

3. MALFORMED_URL : This counter will track urls which not have proper url sytax or url encoding issue
4. HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW/URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW :

   > 

   > ```
   >   if (maxCount > 0) {int[] hostCount = hostCounts.get(hostordomain);
   >   if (hostCount == null) {
   >     hostCount = new int[]{1, 0};
   >     hostCounts.put(hostordomain, hostCount);
   >   }
   >   // increment hostCount
   >   hostCount[1]++;
   >
   >   // check if topN reached, select next segment if it is
   >   while (segCounts[hostCount[0] - 1] >= limit
   >           && hostCount[0] < maxNumSegments) {
   >     hostCount[0]++;
   >     hostCount[1] = 0;
   >   }
   >
   >   // reached the limit of allowed URLs per host / domain
   >   // see if we can put it in the next segment?
   >   if (hostCount[1] > maxCount) {
   >     if (hostCount[0] < maxNumSegments) {
   >       hostCount[0]++;
   >       hostCount[1] = 1;
   >     } else {
   >       if (hostCount[1] == (maxCount + 1)) {
   >         context
   >                 .getCounter("Generator", "HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW")
   >                 .increment(1);
   >         LOG.info(
   >                 "Host or domain {} has more than {} URLs for all {} segments. Additional URLs won't be included in the fetchlist.",
   >                 hostordomain, maxCount, maxNumSegments);
   >       }
   >       // skip this entry
   >       context.getCounter("Generator", "URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW")
   >               .increment(1);
   >       continue;
   >     }
   >   }
   >   entry.segnum = new IntWritable(hostCount[0]);
   >   segCounts[hostCount[0] - 1]++;
   > } else {
   >   entry.segnum = new IntWritable(currentsegmentnum);
   >   segCounts[currentsegmentnum - 1]++;
   > }
   > ```

   As per above code **hostCounts** object is used to track <domain,[segmentNumber,urlCounts]>
   `hostCount[1] == ([maxCount][4] + 1) && hostCount[0] > maxNumSegments` will be true only when we reached full threadhold per domain for all the  segments and count will be tracted in **HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW**.

**HOSTS_AFFECTED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW**
It basically tracks all the hosts/domains which missed to **allocated by margin of 1 space in the final segment**.

**URLS_SKIPPED_PER_HOST_OVERFLOW** is used to count all the domain/hosts which got no room to fill in all the segments.

5. And Other Counters like **INTERVAL_REJECTED,SCORE_TOO_LOW,STATUS_REJECTED** are all self-explanatory and for better clarity you can check Generator code.

Comment: @Ravi Kiran Please feel free to upvote or accept the answer.  if it answers your question.